# Oracle SQL Error occurred in XML processing for a query

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I am trying to run this query but getting this error

**Query 1**

```
select OWNER,table_name, 
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count
from all_tables
```

**Runs fine**

**Query 2** - Included additional columns (sample_size, last_analyzed)

```
select OWNER,table_name, 
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count,
       sample_size, last_analyzed 
from all_tables
```

**Error** - ?

```
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 176
ORA-06512: at line 1
19202. 00000 -  "Error occurred in XML processing%s"
*Cause:    An error occurred when processing the XML function
*Action:   Check the given error message and fix the appropriate problem
```

**Query 2 - Issue what could be the issue ?** - Explanation and resolution

Comment: Dont use all_tables as it contains all the tables on which you have rights. Even if only insert right on table. So you can use metadata table for privilege and find the tables on which your user has select grants + own tablea

Comment: @ Popeye so in which table i need to search for ?

Comment: `from all_tables where  Owner = you or you have select grant on table`. [USER_TAB_PRIVS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2661.htm)

Comment: A privilege issue should raise ORA-01031. I think you have a table name with a special character in it. Try `select * from all_tables where regexp_instr(table_name, '[^[:alnum:]$_]')>0;`

Comment: Alternately, run `select 'select 1 from '||owner||'.'||table_name as q from all_tables`, copy/paste the output and run it as a script to see which table name causes an issue.